# Is it possible to Proxy a JavaScript class's extended methods

Tags: javascript, class, es6-proxy

Given a class like:

```js
class A {}
```

Is it possible to modify in any way so that I can proxy when methods are subclassed like so:

```js
// proxy the `A` object in some way
const handler = {
  get(target, property) {
    console.log("getting", arguments);
    return target[property];
  },
  set(target, property, value) {
    console.log("setting", arguments);
    return target[property] = value;
  },
};

const A_proxied = new Proxy(A, handler);
```

I want the message `setting hello` (or similar) to be logged in the following case.

```js
class B extends A_proxied {
  hello() {
    return "world";
  }
}
```

The above code just logs `getting prototype` and nothing else. Any ideas?

Comment: Well `hello` is neither a getter nor a setter and is not getting or setting a property, so I wouldn't expect it to trigger the Proxied getter or setter. If `hello` was `get hello() { return "world"; }` then it might be different...

Comment: No, doesn't look like it. Looking at the [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation) the only time `A_proxied` is interacted with is when its `.prototype` is accessed.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a `class` that should be subclassed for this. Inheritance is the wrong solution to your problem, and proxies won't help either.

If you want someone to execute code when defining a class, give them a function to call:

```
const B = A(class {
  hello() {
    return "world";
  }
});
```

You can declare it as

```
function A(cls) {
  for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(cls.prototype)) {
    if (key == 'constructor') continue;
    console.log(`setting ${key}`);
  }
  return cls;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `construct` trap in the `Proxy`'s handler:

```js
// proxy the `A` object in some way
const handler = {
  construct(_, args, constructor){
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(constructor.prototype).forEach(name => name === 'constructor' || console.log('setting', name));
    return Reflect.construct(...arguments);
  }
};

class A{}

const A_proxied = new Proxy(A, handler);

class B extends A_proxied {
  hello() {
    return "world";
  }
}

const b = new B;
```